# jQuery File Upload hooked to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

I am attempting to use the jQuery File Upload Plugin [here](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

The behavior I want is similar to the home page that loads - i.e - the ability to select multiple files - when selected I don't need the button to upload files individually (just remove with the cancel button individually) and remove all with the cancel button along the top bar

I am developing my site in c# mvc and the file gets uploaded to a ECM solution via CMIS Browser Bindings so I dont actually hit an MVC controller method.  As I am using Browser Bindings I need to upload each file individually to the CMIS Endpoint.  The code works fine doing an auto data submit for each file

So the working code I have is:

```
  $('#uploadFile').fileupload({
        replaceFileInput: false,
        singleFileUploads: true,
        add: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                data.url = 'mycmis_url';
                data.type = 'POST';
                data.submit();
            });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            alert("Done");
        }
    });
```

If I do have 3 files selected to upload I will get 3 'Done' alerts but the 3 files all upload successfully.  However as mentioned the behavior I want is one Uppload All button that would trigger the upload for each of my selected files.  I have the code below:

```
  $('#uploadFile').fileupload({
    replaceFileInput: false,
    singleFileUploads: true,
    autoUpload: false,
    add: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            data.url = 'mycmis_url';
            data.type = 'POST';
        });
        $("#uploadAllFilesBtn").unbind('click').on('click', function () { data.submit(); });
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        alert("Done");
    }
});
```

So I have set the autoUpload property to false but if I select two files and then click my Upload All Files button as my uploadAllFiles button is outside my each loop if my first selected file is called foo.txt and my 2nd selected file is bar.txt it will only upload bar.txt.

Has anyone got any idea how I could have a button called upload all that would trigger a data.submit for each individual file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorporating code from [your later question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27217383/859640):

```
$('#uploadFile').fileupload({
    replaceFileInput: false,
    singleFileUploads: true,
    add: function(event, data) {
        data.url = 'myUrl';
        data.type = 'POST';
        data.context = $('<tr>'
                + '<td><strong>Selected File : </strong>' + data.files[0].name + '</td>'
                + '<td>&nbsp;</td>'
                + '<td><button type="button" class="removeBtn btn btn-default">'
                + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>'
                + 'Remove File</button></td>'
                + '</tr>')
            .appendTo('#files')
            .data('data', data);
    }
});

$('#files').on('click', '.removeBtn', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});

$('#uploadAllFiles').click(function() {
    var jqXHRs = [];
    $('#files').find('tr').each(function() {
        jqXHRs.push($(this).data('data').submit());
    });
    $.when.apply($, jqXHRs).done(function() {
        alert('done');
    });
});
```

Note:

- Since you have `singleFileUploads` set to `true`, the `data.files` array will always contain exactly one file.
- The `data` is attached to the `<tr>` element using jQuery's `.data()` function.
- For the "Remove" buttons, the code is using event delegation, which was suggested by @Ekansh's answer to your other question.

Comment: John - this works really nicely - many thanks  - just for my own understanding could you explain a bit more what  $.when.apply($, jqXHRs).done(function() { is doing  i.e what the $ first parameter in the apply is doing?  Thanks

Comment: @TheRiddler - The `$.when()` function can take a variable number of Deferred objects as parameters, but it cannot take an array. Using the `.apply()` function to call `$.when()` is basically a trick to call it with an array. The first parameter to `.apply()` is the context (that is, it is what `this` will refer to in the function). When you call `$.when()` the normal way, the context is the `$` object, so we pass that as the first parameter to `.apply()`. The second parameter to `.apply()` is an array holding the parameters that will be passed to `$.when()`.

Comment: Cheers John - great help

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to add logic to prevent a file being selected that a user already added - so if user added foo.txt and it was sitting in the files table and they added foo.txt again it will also get appended to the files table - ideally I would like to show an alert saying "File already added" and doesnt get added - may be better to raise as a new question

Comment: @TheRiddler - Definitely possible. You would loop through the existing row elements and for each one compare `$row.data('data').files[0].name` to `data.files[0].name` to see if they are the same (where `$row` is a reference to the row element).

Comment: Ok John - I will give that a go and post a separate question if still having difficult getting it to behave as expected.

Comment: Hi John - ran into more problems trying to get the unique file functionality running - I created a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283373/only-add-unique-files-to-container