# Call ajax done only once after files have uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery File Upload ajax function like below:

```
   $('#uploadFile').fileupload({
        replaceFileInput: false,
        singleFileUploads: true,
        autoUpload: false,
        add: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                data.url = 'my_url';
                data.type = 'POST';
                data.submit();
            });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            alert("Done");
        }
    });
```

Currently if I have 3 files they upload and I get 3 'Done' alerts as the done function is called for each file.  Is there a way I can change this behavior so that the done function is only called once no matter how many files are uploaded - so if I upload 2 files I would only want to see 'Done' alerted once, if I upload 10 files I would still only want to see 'Done' alerted once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to change `singleFileUploads` to `false`, then you could do the following:

```
$('#uploadFile').fileupload({
    replaceFileInput: false,
    url: 'my_url',
    type: 'POST',
    done: function(e, data) {
        alert('Done');
    }
});
```

Otherwise, the best hack I can come up with is the following:

```
$('#uploadFile').fileupload({
    replaceFileInput: false,
    url: 'my_url',
    type: 'POST',
    add: function(e, data) {
        var $this = $(this),
            jqXHRs = $(this).data('jqXHRs');

        // Check if 'add` was called for the first file.
        if (data.files[0] == data.originalFiles[0]) {
            jqXHRs = [];
            $this.data('jqXHRs', jqXHRs);
        }

        jqXHRs.push(data.submit());

        // Check if 'add` was called for the last file.
        if (data.files[0] == data.originalFiles[data.originalFiles.length-1]) {
            $.when.apply($, jqXHRs).done(function() {
                alert('done');
            });
            $this.removeData('jqXHRs', jqXHRs);
        }
    }
});
```

Notes:

- The `singleFileUploads` options defaults to `true`.
- The `autoUpload` options defaults to `true`.
- I don't think the value of the `autoUpload` option matters when you add your own `add` function.
- When`singleFileUploads` is `true`, the add function is called for each file being added.
- 'data.oroginalFiles`contains the original file list, in the order they will be passed to the`add` function.

Comment: I will test that John and let you know

Comment: John - using the code above still getting the alert 'done' firing twice

Comment: @TheRiddler - Did you remove your original `done: function (e, data) { alert("Done"); }`? Otherwise, the only reason for two alerts would be if the `add` function were getting called twice.

Comment: Hi John - yeah the add function gets called for each file added - so if there are 2 files it gets called twice, 3 files it gets called 3 times - is there anyway I could move your $.when outside this

Comment: @TheRiddler - I updated my answer with the best solution I could come up with.

Comment: John - Thanks - unfortunately I have to use singleFileUploads = true.  As they default to this and autoUpload I should probably remove them from the setup- just calling them out for brevity down the line

Comment: Is it possible you could update my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217383/strange-behavior-with-click-event-on-button/27217521?noredirect=1#comment42915665_27217521 - with how this code would sit? Which would possibly get rid of the click count I am getting?

Comment: @TheRiddler - I added an answer to [your earlier queston](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27194683/859640) that shows how you could use `$.when()`.

Answer (score 0):

Look around [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) please.

BTW you can play with the following:
On server side, you could send back a special result if all of the files are uploaded. And in done fntion you can check for this value, for example.

Comment: the server side code - I dont have control over - I am using CMIS Browser Binding to connect to a ECM

Answer (score 0):

You can use falg:

```
var IsDone=0;
$('#uploadFile').fileupload({
    replaceFileInput: false,
    singleFileUploads: true,
    autoUpload: false,
    add: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            data.url = 'my_url';
            data.type = 'POST';
            data.submit();
        });
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
     if(IsDone==0){
        alert("Done");
        IsDone=1;
     }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working partially for me:

```
var addedFiles = 0;
var uploadedFiles = 0;

$('#uploadFile').fileupload({
        replaceFileInput: false,
        singleFileUploads: true,
        autoUpload: false,
        add: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                data.url = 'my_url';
                data.type = 'POST';
                data.submit();
                addedFiles += 1;
            });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            uploadedFiles += 1;

            if (addedFiles === uploadedFiles) {
               alert("Done");
               addedFiles = 0;
               uploadedFiles = 0;
            }
        }
    });
```