# Strange behavior with click event on button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am using jQuery File Upload plugin [here](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) for uploading files.

For each file that is added I generate a row in the table with a hidden button (that would be the single upload button for each file in the row) and another button for removing the file.

My code is below:

```
   var addedFiles = 0;
    var uploadedFiles = 0;

    $('#uploadFile').fileupload({
        replaceFileInput: false,
        singleFileUploads: true,
        autoUpload: false,
        add: function (event, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                data.url = 'myUrl';
                data.type = 'POST';
                data.context = $('<tr><td><strong>Selected File : </strong>' + file.name + '</td><td><button name=singleuploadFile type="button" class="hidden">' +
                        '</button></td><td><button id=' + file.name + ' name=removeFile type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">' +
                        '</span>Remove File</button></td></tr>')
                    .appendTo('#files');

                $('button[name="singleUploadFile"]').click(function () {
                    if (data.files.length > 0) {
                        data.submit();
                        addedFiles += 1;
                    }
                });

                $('button[name="removeFile"]').on("click", function () {
                    var fileToRemoveId = this.id;
                    if (fileToRemoveId == data.files[0].name) {
                        data.files.splice(0, 1);
                        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        done: function () {
            uploadedFiles += 1;

            if (addedFiles == uploadedFiles) {
                alert("All Files Uploaded");
                addedFiles = 0;
                uploadedFiles = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    $('#uploadAllFiles').on("click", function () {
        $('button[name="singleUploadFile"]').click();
    });
```

So you can see each individaul button for the file for Upload has a name of singleUploadFile but that button is hidden - I dont want the User to Upload Files individually.  But I have a button called Upload All Files which when clicking I trigger the click event for any button with a name=singleuploadFile.

The functionality for this works and my files upload.  The problem is my alert for the done function.  in the click event for singleFileUpload I have a variable called addedFiles which gets incremented each time this event is hit.  The done function will get called each time a file successfully uploads so I also have a variable in there called uploadedFiles - once they are equal I know that all files have uploaded so i can display this to the user.  This works if I have one file and I get one  created with 1 hidden singleFileUpload button.  The addedFiles variable gets set to 1 and when hitting done function the uploadFiles variable is 1 and the alert fires.

However when I have 2 files - the singleFileUpload handler gets hit 3 times - the addedFiles variable therefore is 3 - done function gets hit twice as expected so uploadedFiles variable is 2 so my alert doesnt fire.  For 3 files - the singleFileUpload event gets hit 6 times.  For 4 files it gets hit 10 times and for 5 files it gets hit 15 times.

Cant figure out why when I have more that one row, why the click all button is triggering the singleUploadfile button the incorrect amount of times?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code binds the event to all buttons with the name "singleUploadFile".

```
$('button[name="singleUploadFile"]').click(function () {
   if (data.files.length > 0) {
       data.submit();
       addedFiles += 1;
   }
});
```

But you want it to bind the event just to the newly added button (not to buttons that already have it bound).

Do the following:

```
data.context.find('button[name="singleUploadFile"]').click(function () {
   if (data.files.length > 0) {
       data.submit();
       addedFiles += 1;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this
change this event binding

```
$('button[name="singleUploadFile"]').click(function (){// Do Stuff}
```

to

```
$(document).on('click','button[name="singleUploadFile"]', function (){// Do stuff});
```

What i think is the bug is, 
you are binding the events to buttons with `[name="singleUploadFile"]` to a click event, b ut the dom elements that are already in the page at page load gets binded to this event twice, thus on a single click the event gets triggered more than once.

What you should do is

Modify this code

```
$('button[name="singleUploadFile"]').click(function () {
                if (data.files.length > 0) {
                    data.submit();
                    addedFiles += 1;
                }
            });

            $('button[name="removeFile"]').on("click", function () {
                var fileToRemoveId = this.id;
                if (fileToRemoveId == data.files[0].name) {
                    data.files.splice(0, 1);
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                }
            });
```

so that all the events get binded to the document, so that only on event fire only one function gets executed.

Comment: I will give that a go and let you know

Comment: with that code in place - now I am getting added files and the click handler hit for 2 files -> 4 times 3 files -> 9 times 4 files -> 16 times??

Comment: just remove the code i highlighted and put it into the document.ready(); it will work, dont bind your evenets to the same element again and again, i hope you get my point

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? All of my code above currently sits in $(document).ready(function ()  - can you update your answer to indicate how my code above should look in the doc ready function?